# Match pattern java and grep strings

Tags: java, android, regex, pattern-matching

I have a string

```
NAME: Colin AGE:20 EMAIL;TYPE=PREF,INTERNET:colin@gmail.com
```

I want to extract the strings after : pattern. 
The outputs I want are

```
Colin
20
colin@gmail.com
```

How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `^NAME: ([ \.\w]+) AGE:(\d+) EMAIL;TYPE=PREF,INTERNET:([@\.\w]+)$` with `\1\n\2\n\3`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
:\s*([^\s]+)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yF9rY6/1)**

**[IDEONE DEMO](http://ideone.com/Wx9lZz)**

Answer (score 0):

This method will work **even if you have multiple words in your values**, for instance `NAME: Colin Jones`.

```
String str = "NAME: Colin Jones AGE:20 EMAIL;TYPE=PREF,INTERNET:colin@gmail.com";

str = str.replaceAll("([\\w,=;]+?):", "##DELIMITER##");

for( String value : str.split("##DELIMITER##") )        
    System.out.println(value.trim());
```

For an in-depth explanation of the pattern, to see what the matches look like (and adjust them if needed in the future), have a look at [this pattern on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/rD5rH5/2).

Note that in Java you need to escape special characters twice, i.e. when you use `\w` on regex101.com, you need to use `\\w` in your code.